# Search multiple columns value using LIKE clause

Tags: mysql

Say i have a columns `(id, col1, col2, col3)` and a criteria with value `hello world`. Now i can do it with this simple query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
    col1 LIKE 'hello world%' OR 
    col2 LIKE 'hello world%' OR
    col3 LIKE 'hello world%' 
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Is there any elegant way how to achieve the same query, since it will be a bothersome to write many fields if by chance some table has lots of it.

Found this query somewhere here on SO:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'hello world' IN(col1, col2, col3);
```

But i cannot figure out how to do this way using LIKE clause. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a nicer way of writing your logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's a sad point

Comment: I think in general you are better off having separate `LIKE` expressions anyway.  If you want to have more than one RHS, I can definitely give you a query for that (e.g. where `col1` is like several possible things).

Comment: Yea, a basic query will do so and sounds like you are trying to bring REGEXP?

Comment: Yes, but this won't help with your question.  It would only cover one column to many patterns, not the other way around.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for your suggestion anyway seems ill do it the simple way then

Answer (score 0):

There is no `IN` kind of keyword for `LIKE`

But you can do like this to look cleaner.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE patterns (
  pattern VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO patterns VALUES ('hello%'), ('hello%'), ('hello%');

SELECT t.* FROM my_table t JOIN patterns p ON (t.col LIKE p.pattern);
```

Comment: i think it is irrelevant to include wildcards to any field during insertion

Comment: I don’t agree with that, it’s depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab  you are welcome, please accept the answer if you think it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using this example:

```
CREATE TABLE patterns2 (
  col1 VARCHAR(20),
  col2 VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO patterns2 VALUES ('hello', 'hell1'), 
('hello2', 'hello3'), 
('b', 'a'),
('c', 'hello19723');
```

And running this query:

```
select * from patterns2 where CONCAT_WS(';', col1, col2) REGEXP '^hello|;hello'
```